# Provide ability to enter text message for down-voters/up-voters

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes, up-votes

When one down-votes/up-votes a question or an answer, it would be great to let one enter optional message, so later, when someone clicks on the number of votes, could see not only number of down-votes/up-votes but also possible comments about why it was down-voted/up-voted.

It doesn't seem hard to implement and would provide useful information to the future readers about why others taken down-vote/up-vote action.

When one down-votes/up-votes, it would be possible to provide a word of why he/she taken such action. Comments are not exactly for doing that and look more like a global thing. Later, when clicking on the number of votes, a user could get useful information about the question/answer rating and explanation about why rating is the way it is.

Could this be implemented, please?

Comment: Here is a place where one can enter a message. [tag:status-completed]?

Comment: I'm seriously considering having a canned comment response for downvote-comment requests. It seems it would work in every feature request related to them.

Comment: @Oded Not sure what you mean, pal!?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev you can comment, like you just did, when you down vote/up vote... no need for anything special

Comment: I mean - that's what comments are for. If that's not what you had in mind, please explain more - why they are not good enough or what exactly you had in mind.

Comment: @Oded When one down-votes, it would be possible to provide a word of why he/she taken such action. Comments are not exactly for doing that and look more like a global thing. Later, when clicking on the number of votes, a user could get useful information about the question/answer rating and explanation about why rating is the way it is.

Comment: And what do you suggest that would look like? Do you understand that we would get a substantial reduction in voting if we do that (also - why limit to downvotes? why shouldn't one have a similar thing for upvotes, following your logic?)

Comment: @Oded I never said that we would limit down-voters/up-voters. I just meant that we would be able to provide optional message about the  decision we made!

Comment: Which is what comments can certainly do. I don't get the difference between your suggestion and what comments can do.

Comment: @Oded comments can do it, yes but if I want to see only the reasons why people up-voted/down-voted, I would click on the votes numbers and be able to filter out these.. Comments more global, what I say more specific to the votes.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Easy, don't misuse comments for irrelevant stuff not related to the post. Then you don't have to filter through millions of useless comments but have only those that are about the actual post and its improvement anyway.

Comment: Maybe, I'm just proposing. It make sense to me and as it seems only to me alone.

Comment: Reasons for my votes normally "the quality of this question or answer is extremely poor shows no research effort in the slightest when I did a Google search the first result answered your question and/or your answer is a comment at best"

Comment: It's really amusing how many people down-voting :) (not like I care about the simple rating) for the matter that I find possible/good to have.. Not a single person likes my idea, even though it's proposed to be optional? No like I ask to up-vote, **no** I just don't understand the driving force of such united actions? It seems/feels that I'm really missing here something.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev don't forget that downvotes not only signal that this is a *disagreeable idea* (-5 would have probably sufficed for that purpose) but also *reduce your reputation* while downvoting a question does not cost one's own rep so is *cheap* for the downvoter. In this way it is made sure that ridiculous ideas never come up again -- working from two ends. :)

Comment: @LoneWolf :) The only problem, I don't see this idea that much ridiculous but I understood already that I'm alone on this matter.

Comment: +1. I like your idea. The reason might simply be given on a categorical scale (which would also make sure that there are *ex ante* criteria for voting (up/down) so there is no not voting like a [*Texan sharpshooter*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy#cite_note-2). There could also be the category *other reasons* which could then lead to an (*optional*) comment. So voting would be just a bit more streamlined -- and still anonymous.

Answer (score 4):

Comments are there exactly for the purpose you describe: to ask for clarification or for constructive criticism.

Downvoting is a way to express the question is not useful, not well-researched or unclear. Comments can give a more to the point way to indicate what could be changed or clarified.

There is no use in another mechanism to do exactly what comments do. If enough users agree, these comments will automatically float to the top (they will not get filtered out when there are more comments).

Please don't force users to give up their anonymity when voting by requiring a reason for downvoting!

Comment: Patrick, I've been quite a long time at Stack Exchange, I know all about comments and how things work in general - I think there is room for improvement in this regard and this is why I'm proposing. Comments are fine but not the best option in this case scenario. (As on comments there might be other ideas, totally unrelated to the reasons of voting). However, comments above explicitly described your idea in the answer, which makes it redundant and thus meaningless.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev except people won't provide helpful commentary if they are forced to provide it(including myself) who normal does just to spite being forced to.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Comments are mere asides to Questions and Answers so until any useful content in comments makes it into one or other they may have been made but are far from permanent.

Comment: As written in my comment above if there would be a *categorical scale* voting would simply be a bit more streamlined, there would still be anonymity and always (optional) comments. Can't see this as anything but an *improvement*.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why down-voters are not forced to leave a message or a comment is that down-votes are supposed to be anonymous. Everybody can leave a comment, so you cannot know if the users who commented down-voted you, but a message that would be left only from users who down-voted would make it easy for the OP to understand the users who down-voted, which is not something Stack Exchange wants.

Considering what the tooltips for the down-vote buttons say, I don't see why users would leave a message for a down-vote they leave, when they can eventually comment on what is wrong in the post. If they don't have anything to add to what those tooltips show, they don't leave a comment.

#### Questions

This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

#### Answers

This answer is not useful

Plus, the *responsability* of explaining what is bad in a post is not just for down-voters; everybody in a Stack Exchange site can explain in a comment what is wrong with a post.

Comment: Being anonymous is great in one way but it should be optional (like I said: *enter optional message*). If you want to be anonymous, great, just vote and leave no message. If you want to step out of the shadow, no problem, go ahead and enter your comment, so whoever wishes to see the number of votes, would also be able to read voluntarily left comments to the voting action. Sounds perfectly fine for me, not sure why you don't see it valuable.

Comment: Nobody wants to get down-voting revenge, so nobody would enter an optional message they know it identify them as down-voters. Plus, the down-vote button already give a description for the down-vote.

Comment: :D *down-voting revenge* - that sounds amazingly funny! Normal human being would never do a revenge. (especially like that one - I'll down-vote you just because you had a reason to down-vote me)

Comment: Both up-vote and down-vote 'revenges' are the subject of serial-voting, so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Revenge down-voting is already a problem since some users down-vote who they think down-voted them; imagine if they would be sure about the users who down-voted. _Serial-voting_ is something different from _revenge-down-voting_, then.

Comment: What you're saying is destructive to the community and then I would agree. At the same time, if one chooses to leave a comment upon down-voting, the other system should control further cross-interaction in-between the users, who would be potential *enemies*. It would require some work but it would expand current functionality.

Did you ever wonder why Google made all Likes/Dislikes public?

Comment: Likes/dislikes are a completely different thing, since they don't change reputation (which is not even a concept Google has). Plus, if I recall, Google doesn't make you comment on dislikes.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't. Anyway, thanks for sharing your thoughts.